# Does spark provide a way to generate 64 bit random salt?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using Pyspark and looking to generate random cryptographic salt as an additional column in my data frame. I want to use that in generating either Hash or a Format Preserving Encryption cipher values for my data. Are there any best practices in Spark dataframe API to generate cryptographic salt?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but this is how I've done it:

```
import random
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

npart = 50000
def rand(n = npart):
    return random.randint(1, n)

salt = udf(rand, IntegerType())

DF.withColumn("salt", salt())
```